# Dojo PostCreate issue

Tags: dojo

I have a custom widget which has a content pane (among other things). In it I have a multiselect listbox. I have a assigned a `dojoAttachPoint` to the listbox.

I want to populate the listbox when the widget is created.

In `postCreate` I try to fill the listbox with items, but the reference to
`this.selectFrom` (which is the `dojoAttachPoint`) is null.

Why would this not be available in `postCreate`? Any workarounds?

Thanks in advance

HTML:

```
<div dojoType='dijit.layout.ContentPane'>
  <select name="drop1" style='width:200px;'
      id="selectTo" dojoAttachPoint='selectTo'
      size="10" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">second col</option>
    <option value="2">option two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
postCreate: function (){
  this.inherited (arguments);
  var newOption = document.createElement('option');
  text = 'Mark Brown';
  value = '1';
  selectTo.options [this.selectTo.options.length] = new Option (name,value);
}
```

`this.selectTo` is `null` and it shouldn't be.

Thanks

Comment: Hard to help without some code snippet.  As far as I can tell, what you're describing works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/fAZGF/

Comment: Your code snippet looks like it might've gotten mangled.  Can you make sure your templateString (or separate HTML template) is viewable in it?  Something that we can plug in and run to troubleshoot would be even better.

Comment: for some reason it's not showing the template. Anyway, I have solved the problem. It was my mistake. the reference to this.selectTo (which was null) was inside an anonymous function which basically has the xhr call to my web service to get the list of users and populate the listbox. Since I was using 'this' inside the anonymous function, it has coming up as null. Common mistake. So I saved a referece to 'this' inside postCreate(), var _this = this and used _this.selectTo insead and it works fine. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: that's not what's posted above, right?  If you do have an anonymous function callback and you care about the value of 'this', you may want to try dojo.hitch.  It will do what you describe without the awkward variable reference through the closure.

Comment: That's right, sorry about that. I didn't post that part of the code since I didn't think it was relevant to the question, but apparently it was.

Answer (score 1):

I think dojoAttachPoint is only meaningful in templates (see dijit._Templated)  Templates are separate strings/files which are used to compose widgets and are generally not used inline in the page.